# Unable to Fetch twitter tweets

Tags: twitter, tweetinvi

I am getting twiiter feeds now a days. I am using tweetinvi Api, my code fetch only latest 200 feeds,and i want all.

my code is
Public Function getTweets()

```
    ''Set the credentials
    Dim lObjConsumerKey As String = "[REDACTED]"
    Dim lObjConsumerSecret As String = "[REDACTED]"
    Dim lObjUserAccessToken As String = "[REDACTED]"
    Dim lObjUserAccessSecret As String = "[REDACTED]"
    Auth.SetUserCredentials(lObjConsumerKey, lObjConsumerSecret, lObjUserAccessToken, lObjUserAccessSecret)
    Dim lObjDataTable As New DataTable

    lObjDataTable.Columns.Add("Tweets")
    lObjDataTable.Columns.Add("CreatedAt")

    Dim GetTimelineTweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(txtUserName.Text)
    For Each lobjGetgetTweets In GetTimelineTweets

        Dim drNew = lObjDataTable.NewRow

        drNew("Tweets") = lobjGetgetTweets
        drNew("CreatedAt") = lobjGetgetTweets.CreatedAt
        lObjDataTable.Rows.Add(drNew)

    Next

    Return lObjDataTable

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is by design, as per the Twitter REST API documentaion for GetUserTimeline().  In the definition of the count parameter...

> Specifies the number of Tweets to try and retrieve, up to a maximum of
>   200 per distinct request.

To get all tweets, check out [Working With Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines) on the Twitter Developer site.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample for you in the documentation : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Get-All-User-Tweets

```
RateLimit.RateLimitTrackerMode = RateLimitTrackerMode.TrackAndAwait;

RateLimit.QueryAwaitingForRateLimit += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Query : {args.Query} is awaiting for rate limits!");
};

long userId = <YOUR_USER_ID>;
var lastTweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(userId, 200).ToArray();

var allTweets = new List<ITweet>(lastTweets);
var beforeLast = allTweets;

while (lastTweets.Length > 0 && allTweets.Count <= 3200)
{
    var idOfOldestTweet = lastTweets.Select(x => x.Id).Min();
    Console.WriteLine($"Oldest Tweet Id = {idOfOldestTweet}");

    var numberOfTweetsToRetrieve = allTweets.Count > 3000 ? 3200 - allTweets.Count: 200;
    var timelineRequestParameters = new UserTimelineParameters
    {
        // MaxId ensures that we only get tweets that have been posted 
        // BEFORE the oldest tweet we received
        MaxId = idOfOldestTweet - 1,
        MaximumNumberOfTweetsToRetrieve = numberOfTweetsToRetrieve
    };

    lastTweets = Timeline.GetUserTimeline(userId, timelineRequestParameters).ToArray();
    allTweets.AddRange(lastTweets);
}

// `allTweets` now contains all the tweets that Twitter can return
```